# Where I could find values for rare Earth metals levels diagram (Dieke diagram)?

Tags: resource-recommendations, atomic-physics, spectroscopy, elements

The Dieke diagrams like the following could be easily found on the internet:

[image: Dieke diagram]

But it is impossible to determine where they get the values initially from; everyone is making cross-references. I'm especially interested in the $\rm Tb^{3+}$ ion.

Please help me to find the original works, I think from very old times, so I will take their experimental values to compare with my experimental data.

Comment: http://www.nist.gov/pml/data/asd.cfm has many spectroscopy results including reference

Comment: Please keep in mind that the _precise values_ depend on the host material (often a crystal). There are specific articles for some materials as pointed out below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Spectra of the Doubly and Triply Ionized Rare Earths](https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-2-7-675&id=13122)

G. H. Dieke and H. M. Crosswhite

Applied Optics Vol. 2, Issue 7, pp. 675-686 (1963) •doi: 10.1364/AO.2.000675

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 3) If you have a good question, ask it! Just search for duplicates and follow the [help center rules](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). 4) Try to summarize the main points of your link, as links can change and we want our answers to be complete.

Comment: @Numrok as the question specifically asks for a reference, and this provides a clear reference (sure there's a link, but the plain text details are also there), this looks like valid answer to me. There's even a DOI, which is about as link-rot resistant as you can get.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for tabulated version of this diagram..But alas....

Answer (score 2):

For Tb3+, here is a primary literature reference:

[Arsenev, P. A., Bienert, K. E. and Potemkin, A. V. (1974), Spectroscopic properties of Tb3+ ions in YAlO3 crystals. phys. stat. sol. (a), 26: K71–K74. doi:10.1002/pssa.2210260158](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/pssa.2210260158/abstract)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this original document at the link:
http://www.osti.gov/scitech/servlets/purl/6417825/

Answer (score 1):

The numerical values of Nd, Pr, Pm, Sm, Er, Tm, Ho, Dy, Tb and Gd levels are in [supplementary tables](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/suppl/10.1063/1.455853/suppl_file/jcpsa-90-3443-63.pdf) for [W. T. Carnall, G. L. Goodman, K. Rajnak, and R. S. Rana. A systematic analysis of the spectra of the lanthanides doped into single crystal LaF3](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.455853).